# Mod_rewrite does not work when following hyperlink

Tags: jquery, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a portfolio ([link here](http://www.owenpickering.com)) that works like this:

- The front page (`index.php`) loads items via AJAX POST
- These items have hyperlinks to their own `/idea/example-idea` page (which is rewritten from `/idea.php?url=example-idea`)

The problem is that these hyperlinks bring me to the non re-written page (`/idea.php?url=example-idea`) even though `/idea/example-idea` works fine.

Example:
Clicking on the `Pedal-Powered Music Machine` item brings me to `/idea.php?url=music-machine-r48` even though the hyperlink is to `/idea/music-machine-r48`, which is causing problems with JQuery which is reading from the address bar.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^idea/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ idea.php?url=$1 [NC,L,NE] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^owenpickering.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule .? http://owenpickering.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .? /404.php [L]
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^idea/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ idea.php?url=$1 [NC,L,NE] 

#this is causing the redirecting
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^owenpickering.com$ [NC]  
#RewriteRule .? http://owenpickering.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule .? /404.php [L]
```

Comment: Hmm how strange. It looks as if this works for most of my links, but the `Pedal-Powered Music Machine` link is still redirecting. Also is there any way to hide the `www` in the address bar without causing this problem

Comment: please check if some other rule or file are not conflicting with this.